# Android create a new user in Firebase Authentication but with data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

#### The Story

I'm creating 2 Android applications using Java in Android Studio and Firebase as the backend.

The first app (let's call it the **Doctor app** means an app for doctors) has a feature of registering new users to Firebase Firestore.

The second app (let's call it the **Patient app** means an app for patients) has a feature of showing patient's records.

In the **Doctor app**, doctors can save new patient's data such as name, ID number, birth date, and gender like this picture:

[image: Doctor app]

If the doctor clicks the register button, the app would save the patient data into Firebase Firestore (but not register the patient into Firebase Authentication) with this configuration:

[image: Firebase Firestore]

The patient's ID is programmatically generated using a random string generator.

Then the patient can sign up for the app using the **Patient app** using email and password in Firebase Authentication like this:

[image: Patient app]

First, the patient should select his/her name from the list of users (saved by doctors) in Firebase Firestore.
Then if the patient finds his/her name, the patient had to input his/her email and password.
If the patient clicks the signup button, the app would create a new user to Firebase Authentication like this one:

[image: Firebase Authentication]

and store the email to Firebase Firestore like this one (add the email to selected patient name):

[image: Firebase Firestore]

#### The Question

What's the code for **Patient app** so the app could:

1. Create a new user with an email and password in Firebase Authentication **but with the user ID from Firebase Firestore**?
2. Save the email to the selected ID in Firebase Firestore?

**Note**: if it's impossible, I would add email and password fields to the Sign Up page in the Patient app instead.

Comment: Just to clarify, you need to create a new user in Firebase Auth when a new document is created in Firestore?

Comment: you're right @Dharmaraj
well actually, I need to create a new user in Firebase Auth after a new document is created in Firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [implement a custom identity provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) you have full control over the UID that it uses.

If you want to use the built-in email+password provider, you won't have control over the UIDs it generates. The most common alternative there would be to [store the custom ID you want in the user's token as a custom claim](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk).